# Jasmine - how to spyOn instance methods

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a function

```
var data = {};
var myFunc = function() {
  data.stuff = new ClassName().doA().doB().doC();
};
```

I'd like to test that `doA`, `doB`, and `doC` were all called.

I tried spying on the instance methods like this

```
beforeEach(function() {
  spyOn(ClassName, 'doA');
};
it('should call doA', function() {
  myFunc();
  expect(ClassName.doA).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

but that just gives me a "doA() method does not exist" error.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a major difference between `ClassName.doA` and `ClassName.doA()`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Where you went wrong was your understanding of how to refer to methods in JavaScript in a static context. What your code is actually doing is spying on `ClassName.doA` (that is, the function attached to the `ClassName` constructor as the property `doA`, which is not what you want).

If you want to detect when that method gets called on any instance of `ClassName` anywhere, you need to spy on the prototype.

```
beforeEach(function() {
  spyOn(ClassName.prototype, 'doA');
});
it('should call doA', function() {
  myFunc();
  expect(ClassName.prototype.doA).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Of course, this is assuming that `doA` lives in the prototype chain. If it's an own-property, then there is no technique that you can use without being able to refer to the anonymous object in `myFunc`. If you had access to the `ClassName` instance inside `myFunc`, that would be ideal, since you could just `spyOn` that object directly.

P.S. You should really put "Jasmine" in the title.

Comment: We're facing a similar challenge, in which the `ClassName.prototype.doA` method does fire but instance fields are not instantiated within an instance of `ClassName`. The instance fields are populated in the constructor, but unfortunately, they are all undefined when we're spying on one of the instance methods.

Comment: Wow, great answer. I have always used https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery to mock the entire constructor at the require module cache. Not only is it more verbose, it sometimes leads to tests having really hard to grok\debug problems. This is a great solution that is much easier to understand. Jasmine really should include this example in their docs.

Comment: Perfect, works well for me. I was about creating a question about this same issue but you saved my day. Thank you  @mooiamaduck

Comment: A bit hacky but worked for me as well. Bottom line - method returns whatever is expected. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 7):

Let’s do some code refactoring as we want implement **constructor injection pattern** as James Shore mentions that:

> Dependency injection means giving an object its own instance variables. Really. That’s it.

```
var data = {};
var stuff = new ClassName()

var myFunc = function(stuff) { // move step of creation new object outside
  data.stuff = stuff.doA().doB().doC();
};
```

And time for some tests

```js
function ClassName() {
}

var data = {};
var stuff = new ClassName()

var myFunc = function(stuff) {
  data.stuff = stuff.doA().doB().doC();
};


describe('stub for ClassName implementation', function() {
  var stubStuff = {
    doA: function() {
      return stubStuff
    },
    doB: function() {
      return stubStuff
    },
    doC: function() {
      return stubStuff
    }
  }

  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(stubStuff, 'doA').and.callThrough();
  });

  it('calls "doA" on "myFunc" exection', function() {
    myFunc(stubStuff);
    expect(stubStuff.doA).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
```